# How to read a txt file as list of lists in and access it easily in Python?

Tags: python, list, text, io

I have a txt file that goes like this:

```
1 13
#abor# #e#tun###agy#szel#2# #o##h#d#g ##rkasn#o#oka# #a#tunk e####a#akn##$#$#$##$$$$$$####
1 19
ta###t##ertunk ##gy #zel#####ok hide##f#r##sn#omo#at ##ttu## e#y patak#al$#$$$$$###$$$$$$$
6 19
0/# a #a#akon##uli ##mb## ##l#kok jatszo#####del ####l$$$#$$$$$#$#$#$#$$###$##$$##$$$$#$$$
5 17
a pat#k#a###ar##sok #em#j#l#nt##ztek nyomok volt#k$$$$#$$$#$$$#$#$##$$$$###$####$$#$$$$#$#
```

But continues for dozens of line.

I would like to read this txt file and store it in a list of lists, so that I can easily access each character like `list_name[x][y]` check if it is a `#`, etc.

What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

To ensure the file is closed after you've read it, use `with open()`. This method gives you a list of chars which can be accessed as you requested. You can
use:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f_in:
    my_list = [line for line in f_in]

# do something with my_list
```

`['1 13\n',
'#abor# #e#tun###agy#szel#2# #o##h#d#g ##rkasn#o#oka# #a#tunk e####a#akn##$#$#$##$$$$$$####\n',
'1 19\n',
'ta###t##ertunk ##gy #zel#####ok hide##f#r##sn#omo#at ##ttu## e#y patak#al$#$$$$$###$$$$$$$\n',
...]`

Calling `my_list[1][0]` then returns `#` - the first character in the second line.

This leaves the end of line character at the end of each line which you can remove by using `my_list = [line.strip() for line in f_in]`

Comment: You got my upvote for context manager. However, stripping whitespace may not be desirable for the author.

Comment: Edited to remove the stripping of whitespace.

Comment: Your answer would be the preferred one for me if not for the first variant of presented solution. It doesn't meet OP's specification: "(...) so that I can easily access each *character* like `list_name[x][y]`". Please consider removing this variant or changing so that it creates a list of lists of characters instead of list of lists of words.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
list_name = [list(line) for line in open('myfile.txt')]
```

Then `list_name[n]` will be a list of characters from the `n`th line.

However, please note that, as other answerers have pointed out, strings share list syntax for getting the values (for string `s` you can use `s[n]` to get the `n`th element). Slicing is slightly different for list and strings: for string `s = 'abcd'`, `s[1:3]` is `'bc'`, but for `s = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']`, `s[1:3]` is `['b', 'c']`. So the other answers may be more fit for your purpose, depending on what you want to achieve specifically.

Comment: This is technically true, but you could still use `[n]` indexing with a string if you didn't convert it to a list.

Comment: Sure. However @magnarch asked about list of lists. He didn't wrote too much about the purpose, so I treated the request literally (for example, in my version you can modify single characters, while in versions where line is represented by `str` you have to create a brand new string).

Comment: Good point! It might be worth explaining to the OP that it can be indexed as a string, in case they're just unaware rather than requiring this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, I would do this using list comprehension:

```
>>> matrix = open('myfile.txt').read()
>>> matrix = [item.split() for item in matrix.split('\n')[:-1]]
```

You could also put this into a function pretty easily to take a file name and return the matrix.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to cast the string to list to be able to address the character as `line[index]`. 
The only thing you need is to read the file and to run the check function.

```
def check_the_line(line):
    assert line[5] == "#"

with open('file.txt', 'r') as f_in:
   for line in f_in:
      check_the_line(line)
```